# How do I show line numbers in CLion IDE?

Tags: ide, settings, clion

I have tried to read and follow the directions for PyCharm and IntelliJ to enable this feature, but their settings menus do not seem to be the same as CLion's.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C or C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can right click on the left of the editor (that is right to the left of the leftmost position possible for the cursor) and a menu will appear with the option of showing line numbers. Is this what you were asking?

**EDIT** : You can also enable this behaviour by checking "Show line numbers" under

```
File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance.
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Interestingly your solution is applicable for IntelliJ and PyCharm as well.

Comment: I am using the whole family, that's how I knew about it. I actually installed it the day before and apparently I am also having most of the problems you re having, judging by your other questions.

Comment: Been using the whole family for years, never found the shortcut :) - thanks!  The other 'long-winded' way I'd always used was via the Settings/Editor; but your solutions is way superior!

Comment: This solution only enables line numbers for the current file.  Is there a way to tell CLion to show line numbers by default?

Comment: Yes, if you go to File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance there is an option called "Show line numbers" that you can check. You can also find it by searching for "line numbers" in the search box of the settings window.